# Exception in Application start method (JavaFX) module-info

Tags: java, javafx, module-info

I am trying to start my application with the module-info in Eclipse but I get this exception that I do not understand, I have tried to run my application with No-Module but sometimes it works and when I restart the PC it does not work. Thanks.
I am trying to start my application with the module-info in Eclipse but I get this exception that I do not understand, I have tried to run my application with No-Module but sometimes it works and when I restart the PC it does not work. Thanks.

Launcher.java:

```
package VideoClub;

/**
 * @author Carlos Hidalgo Risco 
 */

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Launcher extends Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("views/inicio.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    stage.setTitle("VideoClub");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    stage.setResizable(false);
  }
}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/D:/eclipse/HLC/bin/VideoClub/views/inicio.fxml:11

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2625)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:105)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:943)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:980)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:227)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:752)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2722)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2552)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3237)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3194)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3163)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3136)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3106)
    at HLC/VideoClub.Launcher.start(Launcher.java:22)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement (in module javafx.fxml) cannot access class VideoClub.controllers.InicioController (in module HLC) because module HLC does not export VideoClub.controllers to module javafx.fxml
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:361)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:99)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:579)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:936)
    ... 22 more
Exception running application VideoClub.Launcher
```

FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.Cursor?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane id="anchor-menu" prefHeight="768.0" prefWidth="1024.0" stylesheets="@styles.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="VideoClub.controllers.InicioController">
    <VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="50.0" styleClass="styles.css" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <Label fx:id="title" alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="94.0" prefWidth="326.0" text="VideoClub">
            <font>
                <Font name="System Bold" size="65.0" />
            </font>
        </Label>
         <Button fx:id="peliculasBtn" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#peliculasBtnAction" prefWidth="400.0" text=" Películas">
             <cursor>
                 <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
             </cursor>
         <font>
            <Font size="48.0" />
         </font>
         </Button>
      <Button fx:id="sociosBtn" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#sociosBtnAction" prefWidth="400.0" text="‍♂️ Socios">
         <cursor>
            <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
         </cursor>
         <font>
            <Font size="48.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Button fx:id="alquileresBtn" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#alquileresBtnAction" prefWidth="400.0" text=" Alquileres">
         <cursor>
            <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
         </cursor>
         <font>
            <Font size="48.0" />
         </font>
         <VBox.margin>
            <Insets bottom="20.0" />
         </VBox.margin>
      </Button>
    </VBox>
</AnchorPane>
```

module-info.java:

```
module HLC {
  requires transitive javafx.graphics;
  requires javafx.controls;
  requires javafx.fxml;
  requires java.desktop;
  requires javafx.base;
  requires javafx.web;
  requires javafx.media;
  requires java.sql;
  
  opens VideoClub to javafx.fxml;
  
  exports VideoClub;

}
```

UPDATE

Ok now my application opens but does not recognize the fxml files.

Exception:

```
nov. 30, 2021 10:52:46 A. M. javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
ADVERTENCIA: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 16 by JavaFX runtime of version 11.0.2
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1787)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1670)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8879)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:200)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:206)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3851)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1200(Scene.java:3579)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1849)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2588)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:390)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1782)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3230)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3194)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3163)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3136)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3106)
    at HLC/VideoClub.controllers.InicioController.peliculasBtnAction(InicioController.java:46)
    ... 58 more
```

peliculasBtnAction:

```
@FXML
    void peliculasBtnAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

      Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../views/peliculas.fxml"));
      Scene scene = new Scene(parent);

      Stage stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();

      stage.setScene(scene);
      stage.show();
    }
```

[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0h4kL.png)

Comment: I advise you search for JavaFX naming conventions and apply them (e.g. fix your package name).

Comment: the error tells you all: _because module HLC does not export VideoClub.controllers to module javafx.fxml_ .. just export that package as well.

Comment: sry, but this question is getting worse .. old: A) FIX the module info as suggested by the error message (I already pointed out which line of stacktrace to look at) B) FIX the module info as suggested in the answer by @jewelsea new: C) learn how to lookup resources (periods are NOT supported) Anyway: debugging questions __require__ a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error says:

```
because module HLC does not export VideoClub.controllers to module javafx.fxml
```

So that is a package you need to open to fxml.

Add to your module info:

```
opens VideoClub.controllers to javafx.fxml;
```

Comment: Ok, I have already added what you told me and the app opens but now it does not find the fxml files :(, I will post the Exception :)

Comment: _I have already added what you told me_ - then edit the question to reflect that change ..

Comment: then edit the question to reflect that change  - Edited :)